# WooCommerce | Show a shipping zone/method applicable to country in cart and checkout AND zone/method applicable to postcode

Tags: php, woocommerce

We have a situation where we'd like to show two shipping methods at cart and checkout. Not just refine down to the most applicable.

We have a country only based zone with one method - Free Pickup.
And.
We have different postcode specific zones set up that have flat rate and free shipping methods.

**Our Aim**

Free Pickup will always show if the user has set the country field to the applicable country.
And.
Flat rate or Free Delivery will show based on if it's available to the users postcode (as per default)

So in simple terms. Keep everything the same but always display our Country zone method, as long as the user has input a country.

**So Far**

Currently we're looking at manually adding the pickup method via `woocommerce_package_rates` filter at the function `calculate_shipping_for_package()`.

What we'd really like to do is to intercept at the session set method and add our pickup method. But that's where we're stuck. Determining exactly where the rates are set to the session.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out we were on the right track.

What was adding additional confusion at the time was that we were also accounting for WooCommerce Multivendor plugin which has an extra step in adding rates.

Solution was to hook into `woocommerce_package_rates` and build a new rate based on our available zone specific to pickup and the pickup method by creating a new object with the `WC_Shipping_Rate` class.

By adding it at this point in the stack, we were able to keep our country based method along side our zone based methods.